# Autorun.inf in Windows7

Tags: windows

I have two question about the autorun.inf:

I could not find a complete, or at least a big enough reference about auorun.inf . I want to know about all the possible 'commands' you can do on the file. I know there is icon=path to change the drive's icon, lable=string to change drive's name, open=path to open/start a program, and action=string to give the program a name. But that is about all I know, and I want to know more. Help? anyone?

I know that windows 7 (and I guess that also windows 8) does not support autorun from a USB, but I did see in some places that windows 7 does support autorun from CD and DVD . Is that true? and if so, how can I make the OS to think that a USB is a CD?

Comment: Really? How big do you need it? [Msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: well, at least more commands.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need.

Autorun.inf command reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

As for making a USB drive look like a CD, this is simply not possible. You can make the icon for the drive look like a CD, but if you're trying to bypass the "no autorun for USB flash drives" rule in Windows versions beyond XP, that requires a registry value change on the machine.

Comment: btw, the command reference has been posted by @rene as well...

Comment: USB flash drives cannot be made to look like optical drives to Windows for autorun purposes. If that were possible, it would defeat the heightened security offered by Vista and above where USB mass storage devices are excluded from autorun capabilities. Viruses used to spread quickly via autorun infections of USB mass storage devices before Vista and up killed off the practice. The user can change the NoDriveTypeAutorun value in the registry to enable this, but remember that your autorun entry will be offered in the pop-up list "what do you want to do with this device?" even if this is off.

Comment: But if a put inside the USB an .ISO file, and make the client to open it, when it opens, the OS will see that .ISO file like a regular disc, and the autorun will work?

Comment: And does autorun works from a CD/DVD on win7 always?